# ImageView's picture does not set with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Here in my code I'm setting a picture into an `ImageView` in my `MyTask` class which is using `AsyncTask`, but as I run my code just one or two `ImageView`s has pictures and the others are empty showing the default picture. 
Is there any problems with the thread?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.e("sara" , "this part takes time");

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gallery_gridsq, parent, false);
    iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
   file = new File(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()).getPath());
    new myTask().execute();

    return convertView;
}

        private class myTask extends AsyncTask <Void , Void ,Bitmap> {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                try {
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                options.inSampleSize = 2;
                try {
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bmp;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap aVoid) {

                iv.setImageBitmap(aVoid);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in your log..?

Comment: Do you want to set the image in asyncTask. No need the use the bitmap.you can simply use the glide method for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are overriding the iv(imageview) object every time when getView() method is called and because MyTask is an asynch task in which doInBackground() is called asynchronously on background thread and onPostExecute() called on main thread after that. So the onPostExecute will only update the current imageview. You have to set the bitmap on every image view of grid. This solution should work for you:

```
@Override
   public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.e("sara" , "this part takes time");


        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();


        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gallery_gridsq, parent, false);
      ImageView  iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
       File file = new File(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()).getPath());
        new myTask(iv, file).execute();


        return convertView;
    }


            private class MyTask extends AsyncTask <Void , Void ,Bitmap> {
               Imageview iv;
                File file;
             public void MyTask(Imageview iv, File file)
                 {
                   this.iv=iv;
                   this.file= file;
                  }
                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    try {
                        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    options.inSampleSize = 2;
                    try {
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return bmp;
                }


                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap aVoid) {

                    iv.setImageBitmap(aVoid);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

i consider that you are try to load an image using a url

you can user image loader reference (such as universal image loader) which is best for loading images

here is the code you can have

first of download the universal image loader library from the below
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

You have to add this method your application level class so you don't need to write multiple times

```
 public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {
        // This configuration tuning is custom. You can tune every option, you
        // may tune some of them,
        // or you can create default configuration by
        // ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);
        // method.
        ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                context);
        config.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2);
        config.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory();
        config.diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator());
        config.diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024); // 50 MiB
        config.tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO);
        config.writeDebugLogs(); // Remove for release app

        // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config.build());
    }
```

Then in Adapter class you have to just add the below code to load image

```
// For Image Display options - Failed , Success and Error
// Add this is in your adapter constructor  
DisplayImageOptions userimgoptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.profile_pic_no_border)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.profile_pic_no_border)
               .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.profile_pic_no_border).cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
```

// in you getview method just use this signle line code to load image

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(modelFeeds.getUserAvatarOriginal(), myHolder.img_profilepicture, userimgoptions);
```

i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

**Set the Imageview using Glide Library**

**Step1**: Include the Dependencies in your build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

**Step2**: Include the Glide in Java file

```
String fileName = "1.jpg";
String completePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + 
 fileName;

File file = new File(completePath);
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

  Glide.with(this)
        .load(imageUri)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.no_media)
                .into(imgView);
```